# Angular JS ng-view change store scroll position

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, ng-view

I used button click to change the route to the next page. Angular JS retain the scroll position and doesn't scroll to the top of the ng-view. 
1. Disabling $anchorScroll doesn't work
2. Using window scroll to doesn't work

```
$rootScope.on("$routeChangeSuccess", function(){
     window.scrollTo(0,90);
})
```

However, to keep the fix header on  iPad, the following window scroll works.

```
$(document).on('blur', 'input, textarea', function() {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        window.scrollTo(document.body.scrollLeft,document.body.scrollTop);
                    }, 0);
                });
```

Any suggestions? How to clear the stored scroll positions by angualar js view?

Answer (score 6):

What you want is not *disable* anchorscroll, but *enable* it. You can achieve what you want using the following code:

```
<div data-ng-view data-autoscroll="true"></div>
```

or:

```
<div data-ng-view data-autoscroll></div>
```

as pointed in the [AngularJS docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView).

Answer (score 2):

Minor update to @Rafael's answer.

Since Angular 1.3.14 you can use simpler syntax to enable autoscroll to the top when switching views with `ngView`:

```
<div ngView autoscroll></div>
```

[Angular Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting autoscroll to false on your ng-view element?

```
<div data-ng-view data-autoscroll="false"></div>
```

Comment: You don't have to disable anchorscroll, but enable it. It is disabled by default.